# OpenGL binds blank textures on Android 2.3.7(CyanogenMod-7) while it binds actual images on other Android versions

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

Bind code:

```
gl.glBindTexture (GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);

gl.glTexParameterf (GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
gl.glTexParameterf (GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

gl.glTexParameterf (GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.glTexParameterf (GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

gl.glTexEnvf (GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL10.GL_REPLACE);

GLUtils.texImage2D (GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmaps.get (resource), 0);
```

On Android 2.3.3 and Android 4.x.x:

[image: Screen good]

On Android 2.3.7 I have:

[image: Screen bad]

Additional info: My texture widths and heights are not powers of 2. Textures are located in drawable-nodpi folder. Textures are being stretched to fit different screen sizes first screenshot is taken from device with screen size 854x480 and second with 800x480.

- Device runs CyanogenMod-7.

**My first suspects are gl.glTexParameterf (GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, settings** but I m not expert in them. I tried some alternatives and did not helped much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad news I tried to set texture width and height with power of 2 value (1024x1024) and It worked:

[image]

The reason was this device as some of significant number of devices did not support npot textures.

So as for solution by my opinion if provided texture is in npot dimensions it would be better to resize them on the fly while load.

Answer (score 3):

For OpenGLES on Android you need to be on the safe side as many vendors don't work with non power of two textures. You can either resize all your textures offline, or during loading resize them. Check this class for more information on how to easily resize non power of two textures: https://github.com/TraxNet/ShadingZen/blob/master/library/src/main/java/org/traxnet/shadingzen/core/BitmapTexture.java